# Linux drivers for Acer Aspire 5000

Tags: drivers

I have an Acer Aspire 5000 laptop and want to change from XP to Linux. Do I need to backup my drivers before doing so?

Comment: No, Ubuntu uses other drivers, compiled for the Linux kernel. In most cases they are already included in the installation CD, or will get pulled from the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

No,you doesn't need to install drivers for linux.Drivers are needed for `graphics,mobile broadband,etc`.You can't able to install `backedup XP drivers` on linux.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to backup drivers of your windows XP system.

When you will install Ubuntu it automatically installs drivers (also Windows drivers are not compatible in Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, backup your drivers; and anything else you need. If you need or want to go back to Windows you will need them after installing Windows again. Otherwise you might run into trouble: windows is not very forgiving if you can not install the network card driver and you need to download it but need the network card to work. Better to have your drivers saved on a dvd/cd.

If you are asking this expecting those drivers to work in Linux: Linux uses its own generic drivers for almost any hardware so the Windows versions are useless.

We have our own display drivers but you can also use the proprietary drivers that are offered to you after installing. These are also Linux versions.

The only problem you might face is the wireless driver. Check if it works with the Live DVD by supplying password and username for your network. If it does it will work after installing. If it does not you might need to install an extra driver (by connecting with a wire).